# Why the Erlang shell does not terminate after all these processes have reached their end?

Tags: shell, erlang

In https://github.com/giorgiosironi/erlang-2pc/blob/master/nodes.erl#L95 I spawn 3 processes which terminate after the algorithm has finished (or so I think: their functions return).
I think also the start/0 function has terminated.

I start the execution of this function with:

    `erl -noshell -run nodes test_commit -noshell`

After executing the function, I get my expected output:

    `<0.30.0> - As coordinator added cohort: <0.31.0>
    <0.31.0> - Will propose: yes
    <0.32.0> - Will propose: yes
    <0.30.0> - As coordinator added cohort: <0.32.0>
    <0.30.0> - As coordinator, 1st phase trying to commit
    <0.31.0> - Queried by coordinator
    <0.32.0> - Queried by coordinator
    <0.30.0> - As coordinator received a yes
    <0.30.0> - As coordinator received a yes
    <0.30.0> - As coordinator, 2nd phase
    <0.31.0> - COMMIT!
    <0.32.0> - COMMIT!
    <0.30.0> - COMMIT!`

but then the shell hangs there indefinitely. I exit with CTRL+C and then (A)bort.

Why the shell is not terminating by itself? How can I inspect which processes are still alive from the shell in this hanged state? If it's normal, how can I terminate it programmatically from my test script?

Comment: `init:stop()` is the standard way of terminating erlang in a clean way. It first stops all the applications then erlang system itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell the runtime to stop once it finishes running your function. One way to do this is to use the `init:stop/0` function:

```
erl -noinput -run nodes test_commit -s init stop
```

Note that the `-noinput` option also implies `-noshell`.

Comment: I think this means `nodes:test_commit/0` has to wait for the spawned processes to terminate, but this is fine, thanks.